# CUDA do deprecated functions still function in newer versions?

Tags: c++, windows, cuda, deprecated

Does the function `cudaGLRegisterBufferObject` (deprecated after version 3.0) still work in newer versions (ie 6.X) ?

(I know that `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer` exists, however I'm doing some work on an old colleague's project and I don't know if a bug is caused by this, or something completely different.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should still work as of CUDA 11.6.2

At the moment, it is documented [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OPENGL__DEPRECATED.html#group__CUDART__OPENGL__DEPRECATED) so it is still present/available and should be still usable.

Deprecated means that it may be dropped in a future CUDA version.  When it is dropped, it is no longer usable (meaning you won't be able to compile code that uses that API, in that future CUDA version where the support was dropped.)